# performance of synchronized method vs block

Tags: java, performance, synchronized

I've a class where all methods need to be synchronized (no static method). One of those method will be called once every 50 ms.

I'm wondering where putting the synchronized keyword to have the shortest execution time ?

i.e. Is there any differences between the 2 options detailed bellow regarding execution time ?

**Option 1 (synchronized methods)**

```
public class MyNativeObject{

     private boolean released = false;

     public synchronized String read(){
         if(released) return null;
         return Read(); 
     }

     public synchronized void release(){
         if(released) return;
         released = true;
         Release();
     }
     private native String Read();
     private native void Release();
}
```

**Option 2 (synchronized block)**

```
public class MyNativeObject{

     private Boolean released = false;

     public String read(){
         synchronized(released){
             if(released) return null;
             return Read(); 
         }
     }

     public void release(){
         synchronized(released){
             if(released) return;
             released = true;
             Release();
         }
     }
     private native String Read();
     private native void Release();
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is illegal syntax. There was a brief moment in 1997 when it wasn't, but it never actually meant anything.

Comment: I'd not synchronize on a boolean, because I think it is possible that Boolean.FALSE and Boolean.TRUE instances may be shared. And that would mean that all instances synchronize on the same `false` object, which would be the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have a synchronized class.

As Joachim points out, Option 2 is wrong as you are locking on a) a field which changes and b) a global object.

The synchronized methods is not only the only one which works but the simplest of those which would so I would use that.

A typical lock takes around 50 nano-seconds, so if you call these methods every 50,000,000 nano-seconds, it is highly unlikely that it will make any difference.

```
public class MyNativeObject{

     private boolean released = false;

     public synchronized String read(){
         return released ? null : Read(); 
     }

     public synchronized void release(){
         if(released) return;
         released = true;
         Release();
     }

     // make the native methods static if you can.
     private static native String Read();
     private static native void Release();
}
```

Comment: Option 1 and 2 are basically equivalent since aquiring the native lock or a lock on a variable will take the same time.

Comment: @Giodude synchronizing on a mutated field is not going to behave correctly, as such it could be faster because it doesn't behave correctly. Or much slower if another thread locks Boolean.FALSE.

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronizing on a mutated field"?

Comment: @Giodude Say `released` is `Boolean.FALSE` and `release()` is called. It will lock the object `Boolean.FALSE` but it changes it to `Boolean.TRUE` and another thread can come in as it can lock `Boolean.TRUE`

Comment: @Giodude: the *object* is what gets locked, not the field. if you swap one object for another then the threads are going to be trying to acquire different objects, resulting in concurrent access to things that ought to be protected. option 2 is horribly broken. PL makes a good point that these Booleans are singletons and if some other part of the code is trying the same insane trick there will be bad consequences.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a Boolean, not a boolean. That shouldn't happen with the primitive type right? The solution though would be to use an AtomicBoolean.

Comment: @Giodude If you made the flag AtomicBoolean final and synchronized it, it could work.

Comment: You don't need to synchronize the AtomicBoolean as long as it's final, that's the whole point!

Comment: @Giodude You do if you need to perform more than one operation as the OP is doing. Adding AtomicXxxx doesn't make all other operations atomic as well.

Answer (score 6):

Option #1 works, and is almost perfect, except that the synchronized-on object is visible to the outside, which should be avoided if possible.

Option #2 is very dangerous and probably wrong, as the object you synchronize on changes (when `released` changes from `Boolean.TRUE` to `Boolean.FALSE` it will synchronize on another object!

Option #3 would be this:

```
public class MyNativeObject{

     private boolean released = false;
     private final Object monitor = new Object[0];

     public String read(){
         synchronized(monitor){
             if(released) return null;
             return Read(); 
         }
     }

     public void release(){
         synchronized(monitor){
             if(released) return;
             released = true;
             Release();
         }
     }
     private native String Read();
     private native void Release();
}
```

The idea is to use an object as the monitor that's not accessible from outside your code (see [this page](http://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized.html) to read about my using a `new Object[0]` in place of the more common `new Object()`). This way, no other synchronization can interfere with your synchronization.

Comment: `monitor = new Object[0];` => `monitor = new Object();` I guess.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I was not questioning correctness - it is just unusual...

Comment: @assylias: I'm using an array because `new Object[0]` is serializable, but `new Object()` is not! That's not a problem in this case, but I just learned that pattern this way and it does not hurt. See http://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized.html for more information.

Comment: @JoachimSauer What does it mean to lock an object which has been serialized between machines? I wouldn't have locking and serializable in the same class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: of course no locking will happen cross-machines. But you wouldn't want the monitor variable stop your class from being serializable.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Actually I would. IMHO, It doesn't make sense to Serialize a class which can be updated by another thread.  For a start you would have to lock it while it is being serialized or the value sent could be inconsistent.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - It does make sense.  Serializing an object creates a copy of the object's state.  It doesn't save the object's identity ... in a way that allows you to correlate it with the original object when you restore it.

Comment: @StephenC A state which might be in the middle of being changed in another thread unless you place protections most frameworks don't support.

Comment: Consider `class A implements Serializable { boolean a = true; }` in this class it is possible to create this, pass it to another thread and for it to see `a` as `false` and Serialize it as such.  Serialization doesn't give you any thread safety support, nor any other serialization framework I have come across. AFAIK

Comment: You could make your writeObject() methods thread safe (not that I have ever seen this done) but you would have to be very careful not to cause obscure deadlocks in the process (as you don't have as much control of when locks are acquired)

Comment: Most likely, I am worrying about something which rarely causes a problem.  I wouldn't feel comfortable about serializing objects which require their own thread safety.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I see what you mean now.  But frankly I think you are suggesting a scenario that can and should be dealt with in other ways ... not by saying that objects shouldn't be serialized if they are designed to be thread-safe.  Sure, its not going to be simple because of the "cross-cutting" nature of both locking and serialization ...

Comment: @StephenC I suspect the usual approach is to not worry about it. The approach I have taken is to take a snap shot or delta update of information I want send/serialize in a different data type.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Tada ;-) (referring to the 100k, not this discussion)

Answer (score 3):

Synchronized methods are just syntactic sugar!

These two are equivalent:

```
 public synchronized String read(){
      return released ? null : Read(); 
 }

 public String read(){
      synchronized(this) {
           return released ? null : Read(); 
      }
 }
```

Hence there will be no performance improvement.

**"Manual" (`synchronized()`) synchronization makes sense if either is true:**

- there are different critical sections which may depend on a different lock
- critical section may be shorter than the method